# How can I programmatically set the X and Y offset of a qTip2 tooltip?

Tags: jquery, qtip, qtip2

I can manually set the X and Y offset of a tooltip using the qTip API with numerical values, like this:

```
$(this).qtip('api').set({
        'position.adjust.x': 89,
        'position.adjust.y': 77
    });
```

But I can't do it programmatically, like this:

```
var offsetX = $(this).attr('data-tooltip-offsetX');
var offsetY = $(this).attr('data-tooltip-offsetY');

$(this).qtip('api').set({
    'position.adjust.x': offsetX,
    'position.adjust.y': offsetY
});
```

When I try that, the tooltips simply don't appear.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MikeKelley/Lesu3m0o/)

Any thoughts or tips would be appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit**: Is it possible *offset[ X | Y ]* is being interpreted as a string instead of a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the string to an int like so:

```
var offsetX = parseInt($(this).attr('data-tooltip-offsetX'));
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/depperm/c2rmj6cj/)